# C# WebClient DownloadString() throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, authentication, exception, webclient, downloadstring

I'm trying to download files using the C# WebClient method DownloadString(), but it throws an exception every time.

Every attempt is causing this exception: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."  The inner exception is: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

But these URLs work perfectly if I enter them in a browser.  Any ideas why DownloadString() is failing?

The code:

```
class Program
{
    // URI pattern:          https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/decaysearchdirect.jsp?nuc=235U&unc=nds
    static string baseUri = "https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/decaysearchdirect.jsp?nuc=";
    static string destFolder = @".\Downloaded Files\";
    // Create a new WebClient instance.
    static WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    static XElement isotopes = XElement.Load(@"..\..\..\..\MakeDecayChainLinks\MakeDecayChainLinks\bin\Debug\isotopes2.xml");
    static StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("Log.rtf");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (XElement e in isotopes.Elements().Reverse())
        {
            string isotopeName = e.Attribute("AtomicWeight").Value + e.Attribute("Symbol").Value.ToUpper();
            string uri = baseUri + isotopeName + "&unc=nds";
            string destFile = destFolder + isotopeName + ".txt";
 
            try
            {
                string content = myWebClient.DownloadString(uri);    // <=== THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS.
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(destFile))
                    sw.Write(content);

                sr.WriteLine(isotopeName + " downloaded\nURI: " + uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sr.WriteLine(isotopeName + " NOT FOUND: " + ex.Message + "\nURI: " + uri);
            };
            
            Console.WriteLine(uri);
        }

        sr.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: User fiddler to check the requests from the broweser, and client, make them the same.. This is your mission if you choose to accept it. also use HttpClient. Read the WebClient to work out why

Comment: 00110001 (may I call you 001?): Not sure what you mean by "make them the same".  Also what should the requests from the browser be checked for?  Thanks!

Comment: If something is working in a browser and not your C#, you can compare the raw request (for both) with a tool like Fiddler. Once you know what the difference is, then you can make your C# request the same, and you have ample fodder to ask a question with